# How should I add iCloud support for CoreData App that has data already?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, icloud

I am trying to add iCloud (iOS7 only) support for my CoreData App that has already been used by users for a while. So I need to make sure that all data user entered does not get corrupted or lost.

When I replaced my old app with the iCloud support new app, it fallback to the local empty store with no data displayed. I should wait like one min so for the app to switch to the iCloud store, and my data will be ready. This is really annoying as user will think their data has been lost somehow.

So what should I do to prevent this from happening? Or maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, that sounds about right although even that time (of one minute) is not something you can rely on.  You could display an alert until such time as the store gets switched to the iCloud store, however even that won't guarantee all the data has been loaded yet.  Any time the user changes iCloud settings this may happen so user education may be the best solution (!).

EDIT:

I have just posted a **[sample library style app](http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/)** with support for the following:

- Use of **Local** or **iCloud** Core Data store

  Includes a **Settings Bundle** (note that this creates a settings page in the Settings App) that includes:

  - **Use iCloud** preference setting (ON or OFF)

    **Make Backup** preference setting (ON or OFF)

    Display application **Version and Build Number**

  **Prompts the user to choose a storage option** when the Use iCloud preference is changed to ON

  **Migrates Core Data store to and from iCloud** depending on the users preference setting and response to prompts

  **Detects deletion of iCloud store from another device** and cleans up by creating a new empty iCloud store

  **Checks for existing iCloud files when migrating** local store to iCloud and prompts user whether to merge or discard data in local store if an iCloud file exists

  **Makes a Backup of the Core Data store** if Make Backup preference is set to ON.  Backup file name is persistentStore_Backup_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss. To use it:

  - set Backup preference ON and next time the app is activated it will make a backup of the current Core Data store and reset the preference to OFF

    file can be copied to PC or Mac from iTunes

    to restore simply set app to use Local files (Use iCloud preference OFF) and replace the persistentStore file with the required backup file (note the file must be called persistentStore).